# How do I fill an unknown size gap in an series

Tags: python, list

I have a very large data set of of consecutive values, containing gaps of varying size and frequency.

**The difference between each number in the series stays the same** but after a gap break the series **doesn't necessarily begin at a point in the original series.**

A very simplistic example of this is: 1, 3, 5, 7, 14, 16, 18, 20 (and also what I've been using to test with).

Sample of the data I'm actually using: 1996.40197023,
1996.40199193,
1996.40201362,
1996.40203531,
1996.40240752,
1996.40242921,
1996.40245091,
1996.40247257,
1996.40249426,
1996.40251592.

This is the way that I have tried so far to accomplish this:

```
date = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 14, 16, 18, 20]
ndate = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

diff  = 2

for i in range(9):
for j in range(15):

    if date[i+1]-date[i] > diff:
        ndate[j+1] == date[i+1] + diff
    elif ndate[j+1] - date[i+1] > diff:
        ndate[j]+diff == ndate[j+1]
    else: 
        ndate[j] == date[i+1]

print ndate
```

but I keep getting "list index out of range" type errors.

Is this the right way of going about this or is there a better way (considering I have in excess of 84,000 data points to work through)?

Thanks

Comment: What output would you want from your simplistic example?

Comment: Your program is an indentation error. Please fix. Btw, "between each number" doesn't make sense. *Between* is always between *two* things.

Comment: I would suggest starting with creating an auxiliary array that is the difference between consecutive elements in the original array, and looking for patterns in that - i.e. start with `[date[i] - date[i-1] for i in xrange(1, len(date))]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want to generate output such that gap values stay more-or-less consistent, I'd go with a generator-based approach here.
Yield elements one at a time from your original series, and if the gap to the next element is greater than your expected delta, generate fill values on the fly until you catch up to it:

```
def smooth(series, delta=2, tol=0.001):
    it = iter(series)
    last = next(it)
    yield last
    for i in it:
        while abs(i - (last + delta)) > tol:
            last += delta
            yield last
        last = i
        yield last
```

And examples:

```
list(smooth([1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 14, 16, 18, 20]))
# [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20]

s = [1996.40197023, 1996.40199193, 1996.40201362, 1996.40203531, 
     1996.40240752, 1996.40242921, 1996.40245091, 1996.40247257, 
     1996.40249426, 1996.40251592]
list(smooth(s, delta=s[1]-s[0], tol=1e-7))
# [1996.40197023, 1996.40199193, 1996.40201362, 1996.40203531, 1996.40205701, 1996.4020787099998, 1996.4021004099998, 1996.4021221099997, 1996.4021438099996, 1996.4021655099996, 1996.4021872099995, 1996.4022089099994, 1996.4022306099994, 1996.4022523099993, 1996.4022740099992, 1996.4022957099992, 1996.4023174099991, 1996.402339109999, 1996.402360809999, 1996.402382509999, 1996.4024042099988, 1996.40240752, 1996.40242921, 1996.40245091, 1996.40247257, 1996.40249426, 1996.40251592]
```

This will need manual specification of your delta and tolerance, but you could probably write functions to sniff those out.

Comment: Thanks so much this works perfect for my data set!

How could I change the tolerance for a data set that increased **and decreased  and also for a changing delta** (e.g. have delta be the difference between the previous two values)?

This would be for co-ordinate position data (for X, Y, Z data sets that go through positive and negative values). The gaps to be filled are in the same places as the original set of data if that is of any use.

Comment: Allowing for decrease as well is pretty easy; just check if `i < last` and if so, do decrements instead of increments. Changing the delta to be dynamic is also possible, but you'll have to be careful about how you modify it when you encounter gaps -- if you make the delta be the size of the gap your smoothing stops working, etc.

Comment: where you've altered the answer to add the abs() in the while loop it gives a memory error now. It this the necessary for the decreasing?

Comment: What's the error? And yes, the `abs` was intended to allow for bidirectional deltas.

Comment: I changed it to this:   


`def smooth(series, delta=2, tol=0.001):  
    it = iter(series)  
    last = next(it)  
    sigma = abs(delta)  
    yield last  
    for i in it:  
        if i < last:  
            while abs(i - last - delta) > tol:  
                last += delta  
                yield last  
        else:   
            while abs(sigma + tol) > i - last:  
                last += delta  
                yield last  
        last = i  
        yield last  
          
temp = list(smooth(data2, delta = data2[1]-data2[0], tol=1e-7))`  
  
and got the error "MemoryError"